# CentOS in dracut emergency mode booted over pxe won't access my http/nfs servers

Tags: linux, networking, centos, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization

So I am doing a small project on my KVM-based virtual machines, now I am trying to set up automated OS installations over PXE. Server1 provides TFTP for PXE, HTTP and NFS. The client gets the kernel and initrd from the server, boots, but fails when it comes to fetching repo's files. Even though specific ports are open on the server, the client is in the trusted zone on the firewall, I get the "Connection refused" error (both for HTTP and NFS). Other hosts use those services without any problems.

What I found out is, as soon as I get into the dracut shell on the client, I can't access the server's HTTP, but as soon as I ping the client FROM the server, it becomes possible.

Thank you for your help!